# JavaScript inheritance and super constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, coffeescript

I have found and adapted a JavaScript "class" extend function from coffeescript:

```
var extend = (function() {

    var hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

    function ctor(child) {
        this.constructor = child;
    }

    return function(child, parent) {
        for (var key in parent) {
            if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) {
                child[key] = parent[key];
            }
        }
        ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
        child.prototype = new ctor(child);
        child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
        // child.prototype.__super__ = parent.prototype; // better?
        return child;
    };

})();
```

I am wondering, if there is a reason why they used `child.__super__` instead of `child.prototype.__super__` (see out-commented code line).

I like the out-commented version more because:

1. You can access super properties via `this.__super__.propertyName` instead of `ClassName.__super__.propertyName`. So you have no redundancy in the class naming.
2. This makes even more sense for nested inheritance since you can use `this.__super__.__super__.propertyName` instead of `ClassName.__super__.constructor.__super__.propertyName`

I do not see any reason for it, but you could even still call "static" functions in a "static" way like that:

```
ClassName.prototype.__super__.constructor.staticMethod()
```

Are there any drawbacks with my version that I might have overlooked?

EDIT: I corrected the line to `var hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;`

Comment: Where have you "found" this? Is it from the code that CoffeeScript generates?

Comment: Yes exactly, but I slightly changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not supposed to use `__super__` in your code at all.

It's a compiler artifact, every use of the [`super` macro/keyword/whatever it is](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) will compile to

```
ClassName.__super__.methodName.call(this, …) // or
ClassName.__super__.methodName.apply(this, …)
// or, in static class functions even
ClassName.__super___.constructor.functionName.call(this, …)
```

They don't trust the [dynamic `this` binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) that you have proposed to use (`this.__super__`), they rather went for a static reference of the parent. Actually it might have been a good idea not to use a property at all, but just a local `super` variable in their module scope.

---

Also, `this.__super__` will not work in an inherited method:

```
function A() { }
A.prototype.method = function() { console.log("works") };

function B() { A.call(this); }
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.__super__ = A.prototype;
B.prototype.method = function() { this.__super__.method.call(this); }


function C() { B.call(this); }
C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
C.prototype.__super__ = B.prototype;

var b = new B(), c = new C();
b.method() // "works"
c.method() // Maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Stack Overflow because you did not get the `.__super__` that you expected!

Comment: Ok, I see I get the same error _// Maximum recursion depth exceeded_