# Why is the 'super_' property in the NodeJS util.inherits function added to the constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance, prototype

I'm looking into some different techniques on inheritance in JavaScript. I have been using the NodeJS util.inherits function for my latest project. And I was wondering:

- Why is the `super_` property is set on the constructor instead of the prototype?
- And wouldn't it make more sense to assign it the super constructor's prototype value instead? As the constructor can always be retrieved from the prototype `constructor` property?

so instead of this:

```
constructor.super_ = superConstructor;
    constructor.prototype = Object.create(superConstructor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: constructor,
            enumerable: false
        }
    });
```

it would be this:

```
    constructor.prototype = Object.create(superConstructor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: constructor,
            enumerable: false
        },
        super_:{
            value: superConstructor.prototype,
            enumerable: false
        }
    });
```

This way calling the super function is a lot easier, because instead of this:

```
 this.constructor.super_.prototype.someFunction.call(this);
```

it would become this:

```
this.super_.someFunction.call(this);
```

This makes more sense to me but I'm curious if I'm missing something. 
I also made a [JSFiddle showing this implementation.](http://jsfiddle.net/z77hry8e/2/)

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: Why would you prefer `constructor.prototype.super.…` over `constructor.super.prototype.…`?

Comment: Not sure whether this is a duplicate of [JavaScript inheritance and super constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24699276/1048572) (which is about Coffeescript's `super`, not node), but the answer is the same.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your reply, I see the problem now (:
`this` would not be what you think it is when it is called as an inherited function.
As for not saving the `prototype` instead, that makes sense as well, as the `prototype` could be replaced later on and the class would not reflect the changes if it would still refer to an old prototype object.
I'd give you an up-vote but I'm afraid I don't have enough credits just yet :(

Comment: @Bergi with prototype you can do `this.super` for objects and `Class.prototype.super` for Class itself.

Comment: @JohnS: Only that it apparently does not work with inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I read the answer you have linked. In Java compiler takes care of *this* and avoids this kind of issues.

Comment: @JohnS: Only that in Java `this` means a completely different thing???

Comment: @Bergi If an instance variable (not method) is overridden in a subclass, `this.variable` in super class still refers to super class variable, not subclass. Moreover there is a `super` keywords which always refers to immediate super class.

Comment: @JohnS: Yes, just what I say: a completely different thing. Btw, ES6 will have a `super` keyword as well