# JavaScript inheritance: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

In trying to port a Java app to JavaScript, I'm attempting the following inheritance technique:

```
var grandchild = new Grandchild();

Function.prototype.extend =
    function(parent) {
        var parentPrototype = parent.prototype;
        this.prototype = Object.create(parentPrototype);
        this.prototype.superPrototype = parentPrototype;
        this.prototype.superConstructor = parent;
        this.prototype.constructor = this;
    }
;

function Parent(){
    this.doStuff();
}

Parent.prototype.doStuff =
    function() {
    }
;

Child.extend(Parent);
function Child(){
    this.superConstructor.call(this);
}

Child.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    this.superPrototype.doStuff.call(this);
}

Grandchild.extend(Child);
function Grandchild(){
    this.superConstructor.call(this);
}

Grandchild.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    this.superPrototype.doStuff.call(this);
}
```

It works to one level of inheritance (i.e. `var child = new Child()`) but with `new Grandchild()` it throws an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` because it gets stuck in infinite recursion on `function Child()`.

1. What exactly is happening and why?
2. How can I tweak this technique so it allows me to call `this.superConstructor.call(this)` and `this.superPrototype.doStuff.call(this)` as shown without hitting the infinite recursion on the immediate parent?

It works when I specify the super class in the calls as follows, but I would prefer not to have to do this:

```
function Child(){
    Parent.call(this);
}

Child.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    Parent.prototype.doStuff.call(this);
}

function Grandchild(){
    Child.call(this);
}

Grandchild.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    Child.prototype.doStuff.call(this);
}
```

Comment: In the `Child` function, `this.superConstructor` isn't `Child`'s `superConstructor` when `Child` is called from `Grandchild`. Unfortunately, I am too sleep-deprived to provide a solution.

Comment: No, you cannot use `.superConstructor` or `.superPrototype`, it just doesn't work with them. Scrap them and use static references.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24700014/1048572) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20463145/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Here's the thing: In JS, `this` and `new`, together, are the single most confusing concept to grasp.

When you call `new GrandChild()`, what's `this`?

`this` is an object with its `__proto__` set to the object **pointed to by** `GrandChild.prototype`. We will call this version of `this`, `gc_this`.

`GrandChild()` now executes `this.superConstructor.call(this);`. We can also say that it executes `gc_this.superConstructor.call(gc_this);`, because we theoretically renamed `this` within `Grandchild()` to `gc_this`.

The above execution calls `Child()` and has the same effect of executing `new Child()`. The only difference is that since we passed `gc_this` to it, it won't return anything and **any and all `this`  within `Child()` have been replaced with `gc_this`.**

Okay, so far so good. No problems yet.

But now starts the problem: Since all `this` within `Child()` have been replaced with `gc_this`, the code within `Child()` has changed to:

```
function Child(){
    gc_this.superConstructor.call(gc_this);
}
```

This is the same **exact** line that we saw when we *renamed* `this` within `GrandChild()` to `gc_this`.

Therefore, this ends up in an infinite recursion.

And the only way to implement multi-level classical-inheritance in JS is to directly use the static class names, rather than relying on dynamically set custom properties.

---

If you want to gain some more insight on the topic, I **recommend** you have a look at: http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-prototype/